# React - Colon is being replaced

Tags: reactjs, url

Can anyone explain, why the colon is being replaced in this case?

```
<div className="col-6 text-left">
{
    hasHomepage && 
    <a href={'http://' + this.props.productGroup.supplierWebsite} target="_blank">
        {this.props.productGroup.supplierName}
    </a>
}
{
    !hasHomepage &&
    this.props.productGroup.supplierName
}
</div>
```

When it's being rendered the result is:

[image]

Is this a known issue or do I miss something?

Comment: It works.. https://codesandbox.io/s/n5pvny52kp .. This is just what the anchor tag shows contents in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are seeing is the content of `this.props.productGroup.supplierName` the place where you are adding http:// won't show in the browser content

Comment: This is not right. When I remove the 'http://' before it, the link is 'www,,,,' and not 'http://www....'

Comment: is your code an example? or the real code you are using? the code in your post shows that...

Comment: Sorry, I checked the value now. It is absolutely this what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: Btw it is fancier to use template literals for string concatenation:
 
`href={\`http://${this.props.productGroup.supplierWebsite}\`}`

Comment: @dns_nx if this is the correct answer, make sure to accept it